# 2 Domains showing the same Blogger Blog (more specified in description)

Tags: blogger

Blogger only allows: one custom domain, and only second-level domain or a subdomain of a domain you own.

I’m trying to show the same blog on both: blog.lottie.cat for public, and “blog.lottie.main.us.en869.com” (not intended to be public, stupidly long I know).

I registered and host both lottie.cat and en869.com from Hostinger, all on the same place. I have already set up blog.lottie.cat to show the blog, but is there any way I could set up “blog.lottie.main.us.en869.com” to show the same contents of “blog.lottie.cat”

I am a complete beginner, only thing I’ve tried so far (all on Hostinger’s hpanel by the way, but also offers some cpanel functionalities) is setting a cname record on en869.com for host “blog.lottie.main.us” pointing to “blog.lottie.cat”, also tried same thing pointing to the blog url (lottiecat.blogspot.com), both for some reason result in a Google 404 robot error page.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about having one redirect to the other?  Would that be OK?

Comment: Preferably, I would like the correct url to show. I would want it to be on the right domain.

Answer (score 1):

Blogger does not support this.

The only approach would be to set up a 2nd blog in Blogger, and  manually put the same content into both.   This would be tedious.   But if you set the 2nd one to be private it at least won't harm your blogs' search engine reputation and so your traffic from Google.